# copy array into another array

Tags: iphone

I have an `NSMutableArray` something like this

```
array =[[a1,b1,c1],[a2,b2,c2],[a3,b3,c3].......]
```

and I access this array for particular object like

```
array.a =[a1,a2,a3]
array.b =[b1,b2,b3]
```

what I am trying to do is to copy all elements which are in `array.b` into an another array say `arrayABC`.

something like this `arrayABC = [a1,a2,a3....]`

HOw can i do that..
suggestions are always appreciated..

regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the "arrayWithArray" class method in NSArray:

```
NSArray *newABC = [NSArray arrayWithArray:someOtherArray];
```

See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABCADBE

Comment: Thanks mate...i finally got it running.  thanks for replying man..i am upvoting u for the link

Answer (score 0):

i think i got my answer by myself

[newArray addObject:array.A];

it works for me....

Answer (score 0):

Swift version for the checked response :

```
let array = NSArray(array: myarray)
```

Also for mutable array :

```
let array = NSMutableArray(array: mymutablearray)
```